# Why the value of flag does not change while reading a file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I tried to read a file and whenever I get `"true"` inside that file I am switching that flag but its not working. Inside the while loop I get the changed value but as soon as it gets out of the loop the initial is shown. Below is the script code:

```
echo "file:"
read filename
flag=0

while read line
do
if [ $line = true ]
then
        flag=1
        echo "Inside loop :$flag"
        break
fi
done < $filename
echo "Outside loop :$flag"
if test $flag -eq 1
then echo "success"
else
echo "doesnotexit"
fi
```

Why is the value of flag not changing?

Input file- "f1.txt" contains:

```
hi  
true  
go  
false
```

Output of program:

```
+ echo file:  
file:  
+ read filename  
f1.txt  
flag=0  
+ read line  
+ [ hi = true ]  
+ read line  
+ [ true = true ]  
flag=1  
+ echo Inside loop :1  
Inside loop :1  
+ break  
+ echo Outside loop :0  
Outside loop :0  
+ test 0 -eq 1  
+ echo doesnotexit  
doesnotexit
```

Comment: This is not your first question. Fix your formatting.

Comment: Highlight your program and use the `{}` tool at the top left of the input box to keep the code formatting. Good luck.

Comment: This does output at least "Inside loop :1", yes?

Comment: Please show a sample input file and the output you get using it. Your code works for me.

Comment: @chepner: I have attached i/p as well as o/p

Comment: `sh -c 'while read line; do if true; then flag=1; break;fi; done < ~/.profile; echo $flag'` outputs `1` for me

Comment: @bobah Please suggest the problem in my code

Comment: @Shashank - I tried to reproduce your problem and failed. If you post full script file (shebang inclusive) and how you invoke it I'll be able to try it in my environment.

Comment: @Shashank Are you sure you are running the code you posted, and not something that uses code like `cat $filename | while read line` instead? I don't see how the code above would fail to work.

Comment: @chepner : Yeah i am using the same code.I donno why its not working.plz help on this topic.

Comment: @chepner: Got my answer."bash" did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above script ran successfully when i executed it through "bash".

There are advantages of using bash. Its features make programming more convenient and similar to programming in other modern programming languages. These include things like scoped local variables and arrays. Plain "sh" is a very minimalistic programming language.